# Python Unable to import 'nbt' even though it is installed

Tags: python

I ran into an issue trying to import a module, it says "Unable to import 'nbt'", I have re-installed it and made sure I have latest version of pylint. But I still get the error message.

When I try to do "pip install nbt" it says "requirement already satisfied", anyone know the issue?

Here is my code:

```
import io
import base64
from nbt import nbt
raw = "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"


def decode_inventory_data(raw):
    data = nbt.nbt.NBTFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(raw)))
    print(data)
    return data
```

Thanks

Comment: If you’re using python3 use pip3.

Comment: tried to uninstall the module with "pip3 uninstall nbt", then install with "pip3 install nbt", still doesn't work @CoryC

Comment: Which is the filename of your python script ? A common error is... *nbt.py*

Comment: @Massimo it is "main.py"

Comment: try `import nbt` and `data = nbt.NBTFile(...`  like they do in the [docs](https://github.com/twoolie/NBT)

Comment: still says "Unable to import 'nbt'" @jps , I have a "red line" under "import nbt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python executable cannot find the module.

I suggest these steps:

1) involuntary override

Check you have not saved any of your files with the filename *nbt.py*

2) Which is the interpreter? Where does it load the modules from?

Add this lines to your script:

> import sys
>
> print(sys.executable)
>
> print(sys.path)

The ouput is

- the python interpreter location
- the directories where it is looking for to load the modules

If the module is installed, you can search it on the filesystem.
For example for linux

> find / -name nbt.py

Its location shall be one of those listed before.

3) lookup in specific directories

You can suggest to Python to look for modules in other directories, adding the directories to this environment variable:

> PYTHONPATH

See the Python docs, section 1.2 *environmemt variables*

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html